# Azure SQL Server transport layer error - to retry or not?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, sqlexception

I have received a Transport level error using SQL Server. This exception seems to be a network blip and was fixed for the same query the next second.

```
Exception in SqlRetryStrategyExecutor System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.)
```

I have a retry executor to retry whitelisted transient exceptions. The exception raised in this instance was not whitelisted.
Here are the error details

```
Error Number:121,State:0,Class:20
```

From microsoft link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/cc645611(v=sql.105). **121** is not a transient error but an insert violation.

How to identify this transient network blip to retry the operation when error code is 121 ? Should I rely on Class = 20 ?

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to whitelist error 121 nor class 20. I'd check to see whether the `InnerException` or `Errors` contain something useful.

Comment: New_coder did @Lucero's comment help solve your issue ?

Comment: Thanks @Lucero. I will keep a handler to see InnerException / Errors in my retry policies